# Is MSO and MISO the same thing on an RFID chip?

Tags: nfc

I'm about to purchase an RFID reader/writer for my A-Level computer science project where users can login using RFID. I've found a chip on ebay but i cannot see the MISO pin, it does however have a MSO pin, are these the same things and if not will the MSO pin work as a replacement?

link to chip:
https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/PN532-NFC-RFID-Module-Reader-Writer-Kit-For-Arduino-Android-Phone-Module/263019641906?epid=938636303&hash=item3d3d313c32:g:P~wAAOSwlMFZNAxE

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: I've removed the question on Stack Overflow

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ to the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus

"The Serial Peripheral Interface bus (SPI) is a synchronous serial communication interface specification used for short distance communication, primarily in embedded systems. The interface was developed by Motorola in the mid 1980s and has become a de facto standard. Typical applications include SD-memory cards and liquid crystal displays."

*SD == Secure Digital, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital

As can be seen under the Ref link above, MSO and MISO are not "the same".

Comment: I feel really stupid now. The poor printing on the pcb makes it look like there is no I. I apologise for wasting your time